# Running computation in background thread python/pygtk

Tags: python, multithreading, pygtk, python-imaging-library, gil

Is there a way to run a python thread in the background without locking down the rest of python during time-consuming instructions?

I'm trying to do time-consuming calculations in a background thread of a python (pygtk) application. I understand how threads work. The problem is that each time I run an expensive operation in any thread (example: PIL's image.load() for large images), it blocks all python threads until the operation is completed, even though it is in a separate thread.

So, is there a way to run a python thread in the background without locking down the rest of python? (I don't care how long they take as long as they don't lock down my GUI. I just can't have my GUI unresponsive for several seconds at a time). Using sleep statements doesn't work because my problem is with single commands that take a long time (like image.load()).

Comment: look into the GIL (Global interpreter lock)  and maybe look at multiprocessing package...  if you use normal threads they should share cpu time... but long non interuptable calls will block

Comment: I'm using the Threading module. My problem is that it locks all threads (including the Gui, which becomes unresponsive) during expensive operations in unrelated threads.

Comment: +1 @JoranBeasley, multiprocessing is very similar to Threading so modifying your existing code to use it should be fairly straightforward

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I don't know about the fairly straightforward part, since finding ways to transfer data between processes quickly is an epic pain, but python's multithreading package definitely solves my problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using pygtk, did you call `threads_init()`?

For newer versions:

```
>>> from gi.repository import GObject
>>> GObject.threads_init()
```

And for older ones:

```
>>> import gobject
>>> gobject.threads_init()
```

Also make sure you do not call any GUI method from your thread or your application will break in weird ways. An easy way around this is to use `GObject.idle_add`:

> idle_add(callable, user_data=None, priority=None) -> source id
>        callable receives (user_data)
>
> Adds a callable to be called whenever there are no higher priority
>      events pending to the default main loop.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to run (non-gtk) stuff in the background WITHOUT stalling the main gtk thread. Moving stuff to the main gtk thread as an idle function is the opposite direction of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @James I don't mean to run everything in the idle_add callback. You still run your separate thread, just like you are doing now. But when that thread needs to update the gui (a progressbar, a label, ...) then to do just that in the idle_add callback.

Answer (score 1):

For doing processing on the background, you can also go with subprocess of python. It will create a sub_process (independent of the original execution ) , for which you can use .poll at certain intervals to check the if the process is done . If you run .communicate then whole process will wait for subprocess to complete.  Also, you can refer this document  :- [threading-subprocess](https://bitbucket.org/daybreaker/kaist-cs443/src/247f9ecf3cee/tools/manage.py)

I also believe that there are ways to get around you problem , just by using normal threading in python.